Python mockito mock return of a specific function call
My function under tests begins like this:
def ums_pipeline():
    spark = get_gemini_spark()
    ums_config = get_ums_config()

    sm = StateManager(spark, ums_config)

    all_ums_signals = spark.read.parquet(ums_config.UMS_INTERMEDIATE_FOLDER)

I am able to mock the returns of get_gemini_spark() and get_ums_config() by using:
when(gemini_spark).get_gemini_spark().thenReturn(self.spark) and
when(src.ums_pipelines).get_ums_config().thenReturn(self.ums_config_mock)
But how to mock spark.read.parquet(ums_config.UMS_INTERMEDIATE_FOLDER)
?
i tried:
(when2(self.spark.read.parquet)
 .thenReturn(self.spark.createDataFrame([], schema=StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True)]))))

i also tried
(when(self.spark.read).parquet(self.ums_config_mock.UMS_INTERMEDIATE_FOLDER)
 .thenReturn(self.spark.createDataFrame([], schema=StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True)]))))

mocking src.ums_pipelines.spark.parquet i get of course error that ums_pipelines does not have "spark".
Edit:
this is my test setup - the part for setting spark context:
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def init_test(self, spark_unit_test_fixture, tmp_path, data_dir):
    ...
    self.spark = spark_unit_test_fixture
    when(gemini_spark).get_gemini_spark().thenReturn(self.spark)

I don't get an error but the empty data frame i want to use is not in use but the default one. The goal is to inject an empty dataframe for specific test case.

The latter when(self.spark.read).parquet(...) looks promising actually.  What does it throw here?  What is self.sparkactually?  Maybe it doesn't allow patching out-of-the-box, or in a naive, straight forward way?

added edit to my post.

Maybe just start easy: when(self.spark.read).parquet(...).thenReturn(3); assert self.spark.read.parquet(2) == 3 in the test function.  This is to test if self.spark... can be mocked/patched this way at all.

Actually when(gemini_spark).get_gemini_spark().thenReturn(self.spark) may not match how you call it in ums_pipeline.  There you just call get_gemini_spark without the dot notation.  Likely you need to patch when(module_under_test).get_gemini_spark(...).
